# Проблема с ключами Gradient

Tags: c#, unity3d

Делаю плавную смену цвета от белого к черному и наоборот. С доки переписал скрипт

```
[SerializeField] private Light _light;
[SerializeField] private Gradient _gradient;

private bool _isBlack = false;
private GradientColorKey[] _colorKeys;
private GradientAlphaKey[] _alphaKeys;

private void Start()
{
    _colorKeys = new GradientColorKey[2];
    _colorKeys[0].color = Color.white;
    _colorKeys[0].time = 0.0f;
    _colorKeys[1].color = Color.black;
    _colorKeys[1].time = 1.0f;

    _alphaKeys = new GradientAlphaKey[2];
    _alphaKeys[0].alpha = 1.0f;
    _alphaKeys[0].time = 0.0f;
    _alphaKeys[1].alpha = 0.0f;
    _alphaKeys[1].time = 1.0f;

    _gradient.SetKeys(_colorKeys, _alphaKeys);

    StartCoroutine("ChangeColor");
}

private IEnumerator ChangeToBlack()
{
    _light.color = Color.Lerp(_gradient.colorKeys[0].color, _gradient.colorKeys[1].color, Time.deltaTime * 0.1f);

    _isBlack = true;

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5f);

    StartCoroutine("ChangeColor");
}
```

и при запуске сцены выбивается ошибка outside the bounds в месте обращения к ключам градиента > `_gradient.colorKeys[0].color` . Не понимаю в чем трабла.

Comment: "С доки переписал скрипт" - откуда? Видимо нужно в редакторе положить два элемента в _colorKeys

Comment: @ValeraKvip документация юнити [ДОКУМЕНТАЦИЯ](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Gradient.html)
Никакие элементы в редакторе ложить не нужно. Это массив с двумя элементами( `_colorKeys = new GradientColorKey[2];` ), каждый из которых имеет два поля: цвет и время. Вот этот класс [GradientColorKey](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GradientColorKey.html)

Comment: Не заметил. Видимо ChangeToBlack запускается до Start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 Если в используете `Color.Lerp(a, b, t)`, то зачем вам `Gradient`?

2 Ваша корутина меняет цвет один раз на одну десятые дельты и тупо ждёт 5 секунд ничего не делая.

Правильный вариант:

```
private void Start () {
    StartCoroutine(TransitionGradient(1f, _gradient));
}

private IEnumerator TransitionGradient (float time, Gradient gradient) {
    float Timer = 0;
    while (Timer < time) {
        _light.color = gradient.Evaluate(Timer/time);
        yield return null;
        Timer += Time.deltaTime;
    }
    _light.color = gradient.Evaluate(1);
}
```

Для простого перехода с цвета `a` на `b` и обратно:

```
private float _switchTime = 1f;
private Color _colorA = Color.white;
private Color _colorB = Color.black;
private bool _toggle;
private IEnumerator _switchCoroutine;

private void Start () {
    SwitchColor();
}

private void SwitchColor () {
    _toggle = !_toggle;
    StopCoroutine(_switchCoroutine);
    if (_toggle)
        _switchCoroutine = TransitionColor(_switchTime, _colorA, _colorB);
    else
        _switchCoroutine = TransitionColor(_switchTime, _colorB, _colorA);
    StartCoroutine(_switchCoroutine);
}

private IEnumerator TransitionColor (float time, Color colorA, Color colorB) {
    float Timer = 0;
    while (Timer < time) {
        _light.color = Color.Lerp(colorA, colorB, Timer/time);
        yield return null;
        Timer += Time.deltaTime;
    }
    _light.color = colorB;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Лерп я из апдейта просто перенес, решил проверить и у меня ошибки поехали. И у тебя ошибка `_toggle != _toggle;` .